# Return Key type iOS 14 for SwiftUi custom Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios14

I Know there is a `submitLabel` in iOS 15+ where we can change return key type.

Is there any similar alternative for a **Custom text Field** in iOS 14 for **SwiftUI**?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `SwiftUIX` package: https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX

```swift
CocoaTextField("Search", text: $searchText)
    .returnKeyType(.search)
```